# Windows not loading from either grub or burg?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, windows, burg

I'm very sorry if this has been asked before, but I cannot find a relevant post that could help me.

Here's the problem:

Windows 7 seems to be able to boot from it's own HDD and bootloader, but then when trying to run it through grub or burg it goes back to post from the windows logo.

It also gets detected as Windows 8, and I haven't installed that ever.

My layout is as follows:

1TB - Windows HDD - no bootloader. 
320GB - downloads - somehow has the windows bootloader on it?
250GB - Ubuntu HDD - Grub/Burg.

Now I can boot fine from windows bootloader, but swapping around in bios to go to windows/ubuntu is a pain.

I've tried using the grub customiser to sort out the windows boot, but it keeps crashing when clicking on "ok".

Tried re-installing the windows bootloader, to no effect.

Any ideas?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1457155/

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: Please add a link to the `bootinfoscript` results or if `boot-repair` generated a log, post that link. Thanks

Comment: I went and ran through boot-repair, and it's now detected another windows bootloader (I think) and now both entries of windows 7 do not work. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1457155/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, re-installed windows and it is now detected as windows 7, and properly loads. Now I gotta get rid of "Windows 8" from the boot entry and I'm done.